# solve the initial value

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I try to solve problem b)

[image]

but I think that I made mistakes because when I try to differentiate the original equation didn't give me b)

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fine until the last step. Having $C=-2$ means that $-e^{-y} = e^x - 2$, and so, taking the log of both sides gives

$$-y = \log(2 - e^x),$$

and so, $y = -\log(2-e^x)$. This satisfies the original differential equation since $y' = \displaystyle\frac{e^x}{2-e^x}$, and $e^y = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2-e^x}$, and so, $y' = e^xe^y$.